# How to write a string to a .csv into a single cell instead of one letter per cell

Tags: python, csv

My code does what I want it to (saves only the first column in my .csv) but when I write it back to the .csv, I get one letter per cell rather than the word all in the first column.

```
def del_col(in_path):
     # read file into memory
        file_obj = open(in_path, 'rb')
        reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter='\t')
        data = []
        for row in reader:
            column = str.split(row[0],',')
            data.append(column[0])
        print row

        file_obj.close()

        conf = raw_input('Delete Status Column? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]

        if conf == 'Y':
            # write data to file
            file_obj = open(in_path, 'wb')
            writer = csv.writer(file_obj)
            writer.writerows(data)
            file_obj.close()
```

I suspect my bottom writing section of code as the piece that needs to be changed. Any ideas on commands that will preserve my word in one cell instead of chopping it up? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The quick way is to do a loop similar to `for row in reader` and from that point change the value in the column.

Comment: I feel like `column` is actually a string, so when you do `column[0]` you're getting the first letter of every string

Comment: @TankorSmash indeed you just take one character.

Comment: No it looks like he's got a nested csv: each row is tab-separated, then the first column is comma-separated, and the "column" variable is the list generated by calling strip on the first column, so that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each row in data is a single string, but writerows expects a sequence of sequences of strings. So, it's interpreting each string as a sequence of 1-character strings.

If you really want to just write out column[0] on each row, make each row a list of one string, like this:

```
data.append([column[0]])
```

If you wanted to write out column[0] plus some other stuff... Then it's not clear what that other stuff is, but you'll construct a list out of column[0] and that other stuff, and append that to data.

Answer (score 1):

`writerows` expects a list of sequences. For each sequence, it writes each entry in the sequence to a different column. You're giving it a list of strings, when to get the behavior you want you should give it a list of lists of strings. Or tuples, whichever.

The smallest modification to your code to get the correct behavior is:

```
data.append(column[:1])
```

There's a lot of other stuff I'd change, but that should get it working.

As for what else I'd change - you don't need to load the contents of your `data` list before writing it out. Instead, you can pass an iterator that yields the correct content to the `csv.writer` class. I see that here you're rewriting the input file in place - I generally prefer to write to temporary file as I go and then move it on the disk on success, or just look for the output file under a different name.

Moreover, in this example you don't actually need a csv writer, because you're only ever writing one column. A simple file handle would work just as well. From the context I am assuming that this sample is not complete, and that based on the input you might not want to delete some parts of the input rows. I can't tell what you'd want to output for an input value that isn't 'Y', though.

Your `str` import isn't present, so I can't be entirely sure what you're calling with `str.split`, but if it's the built in `string` module's function that's mostly obsolete. Instead, `split` is now a method of string objects.

I would do it something like this:

```
def del_col(in_path):
    conf = raw_input('Delete Status Column? (Y|N): ').upper()[0]
    out_path = in_path + '.out'
    with open(in_path, 'rb') as input_file, open(out_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
        if conf == 'Y':
            # no need for a csv writer when writing just a single string per line
            output_file.writelines(row[0].split(',')[0] + '\n' for row in reader)
        else:
            # not sure what you want here; possibly a writer object?
            # actual logic to write the output file goes here in place of the pass
            pass
    os.rename(in_path, in_path + '.input')
    os.rename(out_path, in_path)
```

Comment: I'm interested in your other ideas of what to change, I'm a new python user so my code is very clunky and probably uneccesarily repeitive, as you can tell

Comment: The big thing is that you probably don't want to read the whole file into memory before starting to write it out. I'll edit a version of how I would do this into my answer.